# TypeScript function parameter whose parameters can only be simple types

Tags: typescript

I'm tyring to create a memoize function in typescript and the function that should be able to be memoized must only accept simple types.

```
type ArgTypes<T> = T extends (...a: infer A) => unknown ? A : [];
type FuncWithSimpleParams = (...args: (number | string | boolean | null | undefined)[]) 
=> any;

export function memoize<T extends FuncWithSimpleParams>(func: T) {
  const cache = {}

  return function wrapper(...args: ArgTypes<T>) {
    const cacheKey = args.join('.');
    const cacheHit = cache.get(cacheKey);
    if (cacheHit) {
      return cacheHit;
    }
    const result = func(...args);
    cache[cacheKey] = result;
    return result;
  };
}
```

But when I use it like this

```
memoize(function (first: string, second: string) {
  return `${first}${second}`
})
```

I get typescript error saying

> Types of parameters 'first' and 'args' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | number | boolean | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: Unrelated to question, you can use builtin Parameters<T> instead of ArgTypes<T> to get the function arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function type:

```
type FuncWithSimpleParams = (...args: (number | string | boolean | null | undefined)[])
=> any;
```

Declares a function that you can call with any of those arguments. But you pass it a function that can only take `string` arguments.

"But, Alex", you're saying "`T extends FuncWithSimpleParams` should allow for that, right?"

Well, no.

```
type Test = // This is `false`
     ((a: 1) => void) extends ((a: 1 | 2) => void)
          ? true
          : false
```

So function arguments can't be extended this way.

---

You really have the wrong generic. Instead you want the arguments to your function as the generic type so you don't have to worry about the complex semantics of extending function types.

For example:

```
type SimpleType = number | string | boolean | null | undefined
type FuncWithSimpleParams<T extends SimpleType> = (...args: T[]) => any;
```

Now `FuncWithSimpleParams` has a generic. That means the result will only allow a subset of `SimpleType` as an argument, whatever subset that is the generic parameter.

Now `memoize` becomes:

```
export function memoize<T extends SimpleType>(func: FuncWithSimpleParams<T>) {
```

And everything [works as expected on this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgWzAGwgFXNAvFAdgVwQCMIAnKAHygGdhS5cBzSqIgezdQENcWDlkLfLgAmEAGYMIIgLAAoeaEhQAgqUYZI1ADxoAfFBxooEAB7AIo6lAAUAOgdcAXFAbiyqgJSGDwgNa4bADuvAD8qlAuANoAugDciphQAGLCAMYA6nDAABbwSKgAClykXAg6xmYWVrCIKOiYBjj2jurULmix3vJYBjwgCQpyZmBspMBQ4unAcGy8CBAIbHAAXhC6JuaWItb59ZoQejZTuGkuqadZuXtFJWUVet4A3vJQUGlztO9caTnYUE8AL7yV5QUgQYD4Ui8E5pGZzKBBUpgSCkFp2EqMdqqdQHB7PUFvD64L5pH5-ADSEBAhigmOodgAVstcDYAOR2NmeQZvImfCZk34QAAS2Vpgr+dkYEJsEogVJA3MJrnEtjlouABLkvN54Mh0O+Qo1PN5wO1vOJX3B1HwyAmOFh6PpSvNRPJECicoVMVp1ttwBNbz1UN4frtJsBgzN8gWS1WEGO01mvGOcFItBctHoTAANDQIMSRJm6AxGFqgxCQ1AAAYAEieknTwEB9eoBbmIkB1fkgM8QA)

---

Furthermore, now you get rid of `ArgTypes` entirely (which was just `Parameters<T>` anyway), and just use `T[]` instead, since you know the argument type without having to interrogate the function explicitly.

```
export function memoize<T extends SimpleType>(func: FuncWithSimpleParams<T>) {
  const cache = {}

  return function wrapper(...args: T[]) { // just T[] now
    const cacheKey = args.join('.');
    const cacheHit = cache.get(cacheKey);
    if (cacheHit) {
      return cacheHit;
    }
    const result = func(...args);
    cache[cacheKey] = result;
    return result;
  };
}
```

When you get to the right answer, it's amazing how everything seems to simplify itself.

---

> This almost works. My example should have used different types for arguments. If you change the "second" param to number. You get the error I was referring to

If you want to allow any number of arguments of different types, then your generic needs to be an array type, which allows it to infer the arguments as a tuple type of known length where each index has a specific type.

```
type SimpleType = number | string | boolean | null | undefined

type FuncWithSimpleParams<T extends SimpleType[]> = (...args: T) 
=> any;

export function memoize<T extends SimpleType[]>(func: FuncWithSimpleParams<T>) {
  const cache = {}

  return function wrapper(...args: T) {
    const cacheKey = args.join('.');
    const cacheHit = cache.get(cacheKey);
    if (cacheHit) {
      return cacheHit;
    }
    const result = func(...args);
    cache[cacheKey] = result;
    return result;
  };
}

memoize(function (first: string, second: number) {
  return `${first}${second}`
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgWzAGwgFXNAvFAdgVwQCMIAnKAHygGdhS5cBzSqIgezdQENcWDlkLfLgAmEAGYMIIgLAAoeaEhQAYsIDGAdTjAAFvCSoACl1JcE1ADxooEAB7AIo6rEQp0mANoBdAHxQcAAoAOlDTRmoALig0AEooeSx-HhAAbnl5ezA2UmAocQ1gODZeBAgENjgALwhrWwcnERcDdwxIH19Agtx1aLUe7T0W41NzKzRfeIBveSgodRLaea51XWwoKYBfDLk50ghgfFJebvUikqgAdzMwSFIQsNII6LiN2bn5xbz1FbWAaQgIACUHC1GCACtKrhAgByYIw2LpXYfBa4JY-VYQAASOmBGLWwUYB0C+IgAJAiPeczg4igJN+2J00ypH32h2Oy0xOOASI+UG2yLmqKW+2o+GQeRwpwewVBlMFnLWnlJ5O8wNF4p5LLZR14GolvP5SIF8jKFWqEC6hWKvC6cFItGitHoTAANDQIKiRNECMQyMzkTqOQADAAkU0kDuAm3D1E9JREm2D8k2sSAA)

Comment: This almost works. My example should have used different types for arguments. If you change the "second" param to number. You get the error I was referring to.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can this be extended to allow multiple different paramters at once?
I ran into the same problem (for a different purpose though):

```
type JSONValue =
    | string
    | number

type RPCMethod<T extends JSONValue[]> = (...args: T) => JSONValue | void

function createRPCMethod<T extends JSONValue[]>(RPCMethod: RPCMethod<T>) {
    return RPCMethod
}

function f1(a: string) {}
function f2(a: string, b: number) {}
function f3(a: string, b: number, c: boolean) {}

const test1 = createRPCMethod(f1)
const test2 = createRPCMethod(f2)
const test3 = createRPCMethod(f3)
```

So far this is @Alex-Waynes' answer.

I would now like to make this work:

```
// this function sadly does not work....
function createRPCMethod<T extends JSONValue[]>(RPCMethod: RPCMethod<T>) {
    return RPCMethod
}

const myService = createService({ f1, f2, f3 })
```

Preferably `createService` would only accept a `Record<string, RPCMethod<JSONValue[]>>`, so that my linter tells me what I do wrong right away.

However I did not get this done, Typescript does not seem to like the different amount of paramters.

Any ideas anyone?